# @media query with a specific max-width and below is not working

Tags: css, responsive-design, media-queries, responsive

I'm not sure what I'm missing here but the browser I'm using is not reading the styles I have from a max-width of 960px and below. Anyone know what's causing this? Any help will be much appreciated. By the way, my browser is chrome.

```css
@media only screen and (max-width: 1920px) {
 body { font-size:40px; }
 .logo { width:33%;}
 .article { margin-top:-79px; }
 .article div:first-child { padding-left:255px; padding-right:255px; }
 .products_section { margin-top:55%; }
 .products_section div:first-child, .products_section div:nth-child(2){ padding:0 140px; }
 .address { margin-top:9%; margin-bottom:12%; }
 .address_content { padding-left: 140px; }
 .address_content div:first-child { width:32%; font-size:40px; margin-right:300px; }
 .address_content  a img { display:inline-block; width:23%; }
 .address_content  a img:last-child{ margin-left:39px; }
}
@media only screen and  (max-width: 1680px) {
 body { font-size:33px; }
 .logo { width:33%;}
 .article { margin-top:-99px; }
 .article div:first-child { padding-left:255px; padding-right:255px; }
 .products_section { margin-top:55%; }
 .products_section div:first-child, .products_section div:nth-child(2){ padding:0 140px; }
 .address { margin-top:11%; margin-bottom:12%; }
 .address_content { padding-left: 140px; }
 .address_content div:first-child { width:32%; font-size:35px; margin-right:300px; }
 .address_content  a img { display:inline-block; width:23%; }
 .address_content  a img:last-child{ margin-left:20px; }
}
@media only screen and  (max-width: 1600px) {
 body { font-size:33px; }
 .logo { width:33%;}
 .article { margin-top:-99px; }
 .article div:first-child { padding-left:255px; padding-right:255px; }
 .products_section { margin-top:55%; }
 .products_section div:first-child, .products_section div:nth-child(2){ padding:0 140px; }
 .address { margin-top:11%; margin-bottom:12%; }
 .address_content { padding-left: 140px; }
 .address_content div:first-child { width:32%; font-size:34px; margin-right:280px; }
 .address_content  a img { display:inline-block; width:23%; }
 .address_content  a img:last-child{ margin-left:15px; }
}
@media only screen and  (max-width: 1440px) {
 body { font-size:31px; }
 .logo { width:33%;}
 .article { margin-top:-89px; }
 .article div:first-child { padding-left:255px; padding-right:255px; }
 .products_section { margin-top:50%; }
 .products_section div:first-child, .products_section div:nth-child(2){ padding:0 140px; }
 .address { margin-top:11%; margin-bottom:12%; }
 .address_content { padding-left: 140px; }
 .address_content div:first-child { width:32%; font-size:30px; margin-right:250px; }
 .address_content  a img { display:inline-block; width:23%; }
 .address_content  a img:last-child{ margin-left:15px; }
}
@media only screen and  (max-width: 1280px) { 
 body { font-size:29px; }
 .logo { width:33%;}
 .article { margin-top:-115px; }
 .article div:first-child { padding-left:215px; padding-right:215px; }
 .products_section { margin-top:50%; }
 .products_section div:first-child, .products_section div:nth-child(2){ padding:0 140px; }
 .address { margin-top:12%; margin-bottom:12%; }
 .address_content { padding-left: 140px; }
 .address_content div:first-child { width:32%; font-size:29px; margin-right:200px; }
 .address_content  a img { display:inline-block; width:23%; }
 .address_content  a img:last-child{ margin-left:15px; }
}
@media only screen and  (max-width: 1024px) { 
 body { font-size:24px; }
 .logo { width:33%; }
 .article { margin-top:-115px; }
 .article div:first-child { padding-left:185px; padding-right:185px; }
 .products_section { margin-top:50%; }
 .products_section div:first-child, .products_section div:nth-child(2){ padding:0 90px; }
 .address { margin-top:12%; margin-bottom:12%; }
 .address_content { padding-left: 95px; }
 .address_content div:first-child { width:300px; font-size:25px; margin-right:200px; }
 .address_content  a img { display:inline-block; width:23%; }
 .address_content  a img:last-child{ margin-left:15px; }
}
@media only screen and  (max-width: 980px) { 
 body { font-size:20px; }
 .logo { width:33%; }
 .article { margin-top:-115px; }
 .article div:first-child { padding-left:185px; padding-right:185px; }
 .products_section { margin-top:50%; }
 .products_section div:first-child, .products_section div:nth-child(2){ padding:0 90px; }
 .address { margin-top:14%; margin-bottom:12%; }
 .address_content { padding-left: 95px; }
 .address_content div:first-child { width:300px; font-size:22px; margin-right:180px; }
 .address_content  a img { display:inline-block; width:23%; }
 .address_content  a img:last-child{ margin-left:15px; }
}
@media only screen and  (max-width: 960px) {
 body { font-size:20px; }
 .logo { width:33%;}
 .article { margin-top:-115px; }
 .article div:first-child { padding-left:185px; padding-right:185px; }
 .products_section { margin-top:50%; }
 .products_section div:first-child, .products_section div:nth-child(2){ padding:0 90px; }
 .address { margin-top:12%; margin-bottom:12%; }
 .address_content { padding-left: 95px; }
 .address_content div:first-child { width:300px; font-size:22px; margin-right:180px; }
 .address_content  a img { display:inline-block; width:23%; }
 .address_content  a img:last-child{ margin-left:15px; }
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 800px) and (min-width: 768px) { 
 body { font-size:18px; }
 .logo { width:33%;}
 .article { margin-top:-115px; }
 .article div:first-child { padding-left:185px; padding-right:185px; }
 .products_section { margin-top:50%; }
 .products_section div:first-child, .products_section div:nth-child(2){ padding:0 90px; }
 .address { margin-top:12%; margin-bottom:12%; }
 .address_content { padding-left: 95px; }
 .address_content div:first-child { width:300px; font-size:22px; margin-right:180px; }
 .address_content  a img { display:inline-block; width:23%; }
 .address_content  a img:last-child{ margin-left:15px; }
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
 body { font-size:16px; }
 .logo { width:33%;}
 .article { margin-top:-115px; }
 .article div:first-child { padding-left:185px; padding-right:185px; }
 .products_section { margin-top:50%; }
 .products_section div:first-child, .products_section div:nth-child(2){ padding:0 90px; }
 .address { margin-top:12%; margin-bottom:12%; }
 .address_content { padding-left: 95px; }
 .address_content div:first-child { width:300px; font-size:22px; margin-right:180px; }
 .address_content  a img { display:inline-block; width:23%; }
 .address_content  a img:last-child{ margin-left:15px; }
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 640px){
 
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 603px){
 
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) { 
 
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 460px) { 
 
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 414px) { 
 
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 375px) { 
 
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 360px){
 
}
@media only screen and (max-width:320px){
 
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Koffee Korner</title>
 <meta name="ROBOTS" content="NOINDEX, NOFOLLOW">
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="kk_css.css">
</head>

<body style="padding:0; margin:0; background:url(https://gallery.mailchimp.com/0e6cb285290458da56bd35739/images/aff8994c-8857-42f9-9710-4ee69a139dbe.jpg) no-repeat; background-position:inherit; background-size:cover; font-family:Rockwell;">
 <div style="margin:9px; 9px 0 9px;">
  <a href="https://www.koffeekorner.ca/">
   <img class="logo" src="https://gallery.mailchimp.com/0e6cb285290458da56bd35739/images/083fdc0d-16ad-4a16-b0c8-cf61cd0d14a8.png">
  </a>
 </div>

 <div class="article" style="width:100%; color:#fff; text-align:center;">
  <div style="top:0; left:0; margin:0 auto;>
   <font style="">Introducing</font><br/>
   <h1 class="heading-tag" style="text-decoration:underline; font-size:1.5em;">KOFFEE KORNER BARRIE</h1>
   <p align="left">
    Koffee Korner is a Canadian company with locations throughout Canada. We carry over 550 flavours of coffee, tea & more including brands like Starbucks, McCafe & Tim Hortons. Visit us online or in our Barrie location at 12 Commerce Part Drive for <b>$10.00</b> off. Offer includes free shipping when your order is over <b>$59.99</b>.
   </p>
  </div>
 </div>
 
 <div style="width:100%;" class="products_section">
  <div style="top:0; left:0; margin:0 auto;">
   <a href="https://www.koffeekorner.ca/category-s/231.htm">
    <img src="https://gallery.mailchimp.com/0e6cb285290458da56bd35739/images/689d0647-32f0-4c64-b3e7-8a84c054ee47.png" width="100%">
   </a>
  </div>
  <div style="top:0; left:0; margin:0 auto;">
   <a href="https://www.koffeekorner.ca/product-p/73-581.htm">
    <img class="product" src="https://gallery.mailchimp.com/0e6cb285290458da56bd35739/images/e858b5b5-582d-4a5f-a0ac-fa532f535cfe.png" style="display:inline; width:33%;">
   </a>
   <a href="https://www.koffeekorner.ca/product-p/87-709.htm">
    <img class="product" src="https://gallery.mailchimp.com/0e6cb285290458da56bd35739/images/4b18a285-c094-43bd-8270-fb8f7637e61f.png" style="display:inline; width:32%;">
   </a>
   <a href="https://www.koffeekorner.ca/product-p/41-376.htm">
    <img class="product" src="https://gallery.mailchimp.com/0e6cb285290458da56bd35739/images/088db292-904e-4e14-9dd8-126fd5b30d67.png" style="display:inline; width:32%;">
   </a>
  </div>
 </div>


 <div style="width:100%;" class="address">
  <div style="top:0; left:0; margin:0 auto; width:100%;" class="address_content">
   <div style="float:right;">
     Koffee Korner <br> 12 Commerce Park Drive Barrie, Ontario, L4N 8W8
   </div>
   <a href="https://www.koffeekorner.ca/">
    <img src="https://gallery.mailchimp.com/0e6cb285290458da56bd35739/images/d1e677be-a60f-4d3d-88a8-3a4bd1fe7e19.png" />
   </a>
   <a href="https://www.koffeekorner.ca/">
    <img src="https://gallery.mailchimp.com/0e6cb285290458da56bd35739/images/0c9f5695-69fc-460a-b6ae-e1f51f58035b.png" />
   </a>
  </div>
 </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The media query entries at 960 and below seem fine http://codepen.io/anon/pen/mWVpaZ http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic *"Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself."* Please give us a [mcve] that illustrates the problem.

Comment: Hey man, I've updated my question. I included my html, so that you'll see.

Comment: The media queries at 960 and below are firing fine. Please be more specific in what isn't working. Btw you have unclosed quotes this tag `<div style="top:0; left:0; margin:0 auto;>`

Comment: Sorry. max-width of 960px and below isn't working. I mean, when I'm checking the css using the browser's developer mode and responsive view, the style withing 960px width is not showing in the dev mode when the screen width is lower than 980px.

Comment: Lower screen width were only reading the styles in 980px even the current screen is 360px. Oh, good catch with the unclosed tag. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think you are overriding all your rules because you are declaring the max-width but never the min-width. So your rules are stacking, they all go from 0px (no min-width declared) to your max-width.

Even if theoretically this could work, I think its a better practice to always call ranges of sizes, with min and max values.

Try adding a min-width to all of them like:

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 1681px) and (max-width: 1920px){
    /*Your Stuff*/
}
```

then

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 1601px) and (max-width: 1680px){
    /*Your stuff*/
}
```

and so on with all your rules, following this logic.

Let me know if worked.